# Struggle with equivalence relation definition in graph theory paper regarding clique-width

Tags: graph-theory, equivalence-relations

I'm trying to get more involved in graph theory and understanding harder concepts.
I stumbled upon a paper that proves the clique-width of split graphs to be unbounded.
They define a split graph as splt(G) if it is a clique $G$ with leaves for every edge in the clique (6.1). I'm having trouble understanding their definition 5.1 and 5.2 and consequently the proof in 6.2. How do they define the equivalence relation $R_{red}$? I tried to use their example proof in proposition 5.5 to get a better understanding for their equivalence relation, but this confused me even more.

I thought they color a fixed set of vertices $V_{red}$ and the remaining set $V_{blue}$. But then how could there, in general, be different equivalence classes, since every subset of vertices in $V_{red}$ is in the same equivalence class as $V_{red}$. This part confuses me.

The previous definitions and results on (q,t)-graphs are unnecessary. The only important information in the paper is: 5.1, 5.2, 5.5 and the definition of distinguishes given in 2.12.

Edit: How I understood the different equivalence classes of $R_{red}$, I would assume that given a fixed set of $V_{red}$ and $V_{blue}$ we determine the different classes depending on their blue neighbours.
But even then, I'm still struggling to grasp how they determine the numbers for 2colw(G)$\geq\frac{n}{72}$ and e.g. $S_1 <\frac{10n}{18}$. Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Edit2: Big Thanks to Misha Lavrov for taking time out of his day to explain this in great detail to me! :)

The paper: [On the clique-width of graphs with few P_4s](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2303056_On_the_Clique-Width_of_Graphs_with_Few_P_4_s)

Comment: In general every split graph takes the form $G=(U\cup V,\bigcup_{(x,y)\in U^2}\{\{x,y\},\{x,f(x)\}\})$ for some bijection $f:U\to V$ where $U\cap V=\emptyset$ is this correct?

Comment: For this paper yes, you are right. Your definition of a split graph is pretty much the same as their definition of splt(G). Where splt(G) is just a possible construction used in the proof. In general, a split graph is just a composition of a clique $K$ and an independent set $I$, where $I$ is connected with vertices of $K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalence classes of $R_{\text{red}}$ partition $V_{\text{red}}$ into subsets that are not distinguishable by any blue vertex. Consider the following example:

[image: graph with edges 12, 23, 34, 45, 15, 25; 1,2,3 are red and 4,5 are blue]

Here, $V_{\text{red}} = \{1,2,3\}$. The equivalence classes of $R_{\text{red}}$ are $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3\}$.  Vertices $1$ and $2$ are not distinguished by any blue vertices: $4$ is adjacent to neither, and $5$ is adjacent to both. On the other hand, vertex $4$ distinguishes vertex $3$ from both $1$ and $2$: it is only adjacent to $3$.

Another way to write the definition of $R_{\text{red}}$ is that **two red vertices are equivalent if they have the same set of blue neighbors.**

Proposition 5.5 specifically constructs an example where the relation does not do anything exciting. If $V_{\text{red}}$ and $V_{\text{blue}}$ have no edges between them, then no blue vertex can distinguish any two red vertices! Therefore for any pair $(u,v)$ with $u,v \in V_{\text{red}}$, it is true that "$u$ and $v$ are not distinguishable by any blue vertex", and so there is only one equivalence class. To use our second definition, if no red vertices ever have blue neighbors, then any two red vertices have the same set of blue neighbors: the empty set!

As for the proof of Lemma 6.2, let's take a look at one of the split graphs it considers:

[image: split graph constructed from 4-clique by adding vertex ij adjacent i and j for each pair {i,j}]

We have a central clique (here, it has vertices $\{1,2,3,4\}$) and a bunch of outer vertices (here, $\{12,13,14,23,24,34\}$) each of which has two neighbors in the central clique.

It is in case 2 of the proof that we really interact with the equivalence relation at all. Here, we have a large set $S_3$ of central vertices with the following property: they each have a blue outer neighbor and a red outer neighbor. Now, we argue that:

- If $S_{3,\text{red}} = S_3 \cap V_{\text{red}}$ is large, then the vertices of $S_{3,\text{red}}$ are in many equivalence classes. Every vertex $u \in S_{3,\text{red}}$ is adjacent to a blue outer vertex $uv$. But then, $uv$ distinguishes $u$ from every other vertex in $S_3$ except possibly $v$ (if $v \in S_{3,\text{red}}$ as well). Therefore every equivalence class of $R_{\text{red}}$ has at most two elements in $S_{3,\text{red}}$.
- If $S_{3,\text{blue}} = S_3 \cap V_{\text{blue}}$ is large, then the red outer neighbors of $S_{3,\text{blue}}$ are *all* in different equivalence classes. As long as $|S_{3,\text{blue}}| \ge 3$, if there is a red vertex $uv$ with a neighbor $u \in S_{3,\text{blue}}$, then $uv$ also has a non-neighbor $w \in S_{3,\text{blue}}$ (just pick $w$ to be any element of $S_{3,\text{blue}}$ other than $u$ and $v$), and then $u$ and $w$ distinguish $uv$.

When $S_{3,\text{red}}$ is large, since each equivalence class contains at most $2$ elements of $S_{3,\text{red}}$, we get at least $|S_{3,\text{red}}|/2$ equivalence classes. When $S_{3,\text{blue}}$ is large, it has at least $|S_{3,\text{blue}}|/2$ red outer neighbors, so we get at least $|S_{3,\text{blue}}|/2$ equivalence classes. Overall, we are guaranteed at least $|S_3|/4$ equivalence classes no matter what.

Comment: Thanks. That is pretty much how I understood it as well at first, but I was unsure if I understood it correctly. Nonetheless, even given that information I don't understand how this leads them to results like $S_1 < 10n/18$ in the proof 6.2. Do you perhaps have any idea how they get to such a result?

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you so much. I know also see that I misunderstood how they defined splt(G). For some reason I though $e$ only had one edge with either of the endpoints.

Comment: from the way I understand it, this doesn't hold if we for each edge $e$ instead of creating a single vertex $e$ and connect it with its two endpoints in $e$, create two leaves for each of its endpoints, right? For example, for the edge (1,4) we would create a leaf ((1,4),1) and another leaf ((1,4),4).

Comment: (1) It's not that they *get results* like $|S_1| < 10n/18$. It's that they consider several cases: first, that $|S_1| < 10n/18$. Second, that $|S_2| < 10n/18$. Third, that both $|S_1| \ge 10n/18$ and $|S_2| \ge 10n/18$, from which it follows that $|S_3| = |S_1 \cap S_2| \ge n/9$. (They write $n/18$, but we can actually get $n/9$ by inclusion-exclusion.)

Comment: (2) Yes, the way the definition is stated is a bit confusing, but it must be the case that each outer vertex has *two* neighbors in the clique. Adding leaves would be just as good at distinguishing vertices, but the problem is that there's only $n$ different leaves we can add (and two copies of the same leaf wouldn't be helpful). Adding an outer vertex adjacent two central vertices gives us *lots* of outer vertices: $\binom n2$ of them. This is important for case 1 of the proof.

Comment: I think I get most things now. What I still don't understand though is your explanation in (2). Wouldn't we get up to $2\left({n \atop 2}\right)$ leaves, two for each edge? And wouldn't they also distinguish the same set of vertices? An example for the figure you provided [link](https://i.imgur.com/NaGslOk.png)

Comment: Edit: Even if $lots$ of leaves are the same as $n$ leaves, wouldn't each leaf be possibly considered as the same in $S_1$, because each leaf also distinguishes all the remaining leaves just as we had for the vertex e=uv being adjacent to u and v?

Comment: If we had $2 \binom n2$ leaves, two for each edge, we're adding $n-1$ leaves to each vertex. The problem is that when leaves are colored red, every group of $n-1$ leaves attached to the same vertex can be put in the same equivalence class, because nobody can possibly distinguish them. The following coloring has only two equivalence classes: first, split the clique equally in red and blue. Second, color every leaf the same color it's attached to. Now, the red leaves can all be one equivalence class, and the red non-leaves can be another.

Comment: Now I think I understand what you meant with $n$ different leaves. Since no matter how many leaves we add, we never get the equivalence classes we would have for the outer vertices, since a leaf distinguishes each vertex and as such could be a red vertex in the same equivalence class, unlike in the construction where every vertex $e=uv$, that is connected with both vertices $u,v$, right?